# UIViewController isn't displayed how it appears in interface builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I'm having a problem with my view shifting down when I load my app.  In interface builder it looks like: [image]

But when I load the app on the iPod it looks like:

[image]

I'm not really concerned with why it isn't showing the grey background in interface builder, I set that and it's working. But I don't understand why the view is shifting down.  I verified that I'm not changing the view's bounds or anything in my viewController. I'm just running [super viewDidLoad]; in my viewDidLoad.

I realize you can't see the frame or anything but I can answer any questions you have about the interface builder file.

Here's my didFinishLoading from my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationController *navcon = [[[UINavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [navcon pushViewController:[[GTSpotViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = navcon;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had an old version on the iPod that was somehow affecting the build because I cleared it out and now I'm not getting the shifting anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your view controller to a UINavigationController.  In this case, it will not look identical to how you view it in IB.  Try setting the rootViewConroller directly to your viewcontroller.

Comment: If I make the viewController the rootViewController then there is still the same space where the view is shifted down.

Comment: Can you show the contents of your GTSpotViewController class?

Answer (score 0):

You could look in the attributes inspector and set the top bar to a navigation bar and then everything would line up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

while designing vies in IB therebia an option to set/keep space for navbar/toolbar in the inspector. try setting those values. alos check the resizing option.

Comment: I've tried both having them and not having them and it still bumps it down. Resizing is currently turned off on the view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are there two Navigation controller. check the xib to see if there's a Navigation controller.

Comment: There isn't a navigation controller in the xib file.

Comment: I think you have 2 navigation controller, that's why you have extra space on the top, of the 1st navigation controller.